# Smooth/fast loading of static website-parts

Tags: javascript, ajax, web

I'm writing a small website which has several pages that are very similar. Most of the time, only the content of one div is different. The navigation, header etc stays the same.
At first I realized this with a single html file and javascript code like this (which is triggered by a button click event):

```
 $.get("content/text1.html", function(data) {
    $("#content").html(data);
});
```

This works very smooth but the problem was, that the url in the address-bar doesn't change with those kind of requests. So is it not possible for the user to link to certain pages.
I know it is possible with #-urls, but i want to have urls like:

> example.com/talks/foo/bar

And not some workaround.

To achieve this behaviour, I changed my code to many html-files and each one of them does this:

```
$.get("content/header.html", function(data) {
    $("#header").html(data);
});
$.get("content/footer.html", function(data) {
    $("#footer").html(data);
});
```

So i get my nice urls but now is the problem, that the whole thing isn't very smooth. You recognise every new page badly, because the header and footer comes some milliseconds after the body.

My question is: How to popular websites like [github](https://github.com/) achieve both at once? If you click on "Explore" or "Blog" in the top bar, all the "static" stuff seems to stay permanently there. And in view of their urls I think they don't achieve this with ajax.

Is there something I'm missing out?

regards

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history

Comment: @GGG so maybe i should give [history.js](https://github.com/balupton/history.js) a try

Comment: Yeah, it should do the trick :)

Comment: I am a bit surprised everything i had to do was copying the first 4 line from [this gist](https://gist.github.com/854622) into the second version of my website and the delay while loading the pages is gone.. I was prepared for pushing states and decoding incoming urls by my own. Is this all the magic?

Comment: It looks like it, although it may be worth it to try managing it yourself just to see what's going on behind the scenes. You should be able to get the HTML5 history stuff working with a few simple lines of code.